# 403 Forbidden Error from Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rake, paperclip, fetch

Another programmer has been working on my project on a new branch. To view his work, I fetched the branch and updated the bundle with `bundle install`. When I try to `rake db:migrate` I get a `403 Forbidden` error with no other explanation. I believe it is complaining about the Amazon S3 credentials for paperclip but can't seem to fix the issue. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Please paste here the full stack trace generated with `--trace`, or the full CLI output.

Comment: Have you configured S3 credentials in your working copy? If your colleague was responsible, he did not commit his S3 credentials in your repo.